# How to process multiple files in sequence using OPEN MP and/or MPI?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmpi, dbscan

I'm using the parallel_multicore version of the DBSCAN clustering algorithm available below:

http://cucis.ece.northwestern.edu/projects/Clustering/index.html

To run the code simply requires the following line:

./omp_dbscan -i trial.txt -m 4 -e 0.5 -o output.txt -t 8

where -i is the input, -m and -e are two parameters, -o is the output and -t is the number of threads.

What I want to do is adapt this command so that I can process lots of input files (say trial_1.txt, trial_2.txt, trial_3.txt and so on) sequentially, but I'm not really sure how to do this in this language? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm thoroughly lost!

Comment: You're probably looking for some kind of *shell script*.  It would help people to answer your question if you were specific about the shell you are using.

Comment: I'm using PuTTY? Apologies for this, I'm a complete rookie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any unix server will have a *shell* installed.

Unix shells have been used for automating simple processes since the beginning of Unix. They are *the* scripting language at the very heart of any Unix system.

Their syntax is very easy to learn, and it will allow you to easily automate such tasks. So get an tutorial to shell scripting!